# I can't tell if my betta is sick or not

Tags: health, betta

My betta has changed color and has gained some black it looks like under his gills. His color looks more foggy than before and his eyes have a grey spot on each of them. I put him in a larger and filtered tank last week as well as changed his food. I'm wondering if he is ok and how to help his gills [image]

Comment: what are the readings of your latest water test ammonia-nitrite-PH,what are the size of your tank is it filtered and heated

Comment: Is he eating normally? Bettas can change coloration when you put them in a different tank.

Comment: He is eating fine. His color is changing to a yellow color with grey spots and the black has changed to spots. He is in a 1.5 gallon tank that is filtered but not heated. I should test the water again. He flairs his gills everytime I go up to his tank now. Not sure if that is a good thing or a bad thing

Comment: A betta is a tropical fish. It needs to have water heated to around 24 - 27 degrees C. Any problem with a fish should be followed up with a water test. It's almost always the cause.